# AVCameraViewController.m from Apple Sample code update to latest iOS 11 Warnings

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been working away at this for a week now, slowly removing Warnings and Errors caused by Depreciations to Objective-C code in what is now almost working code. I'm down to 15 Depreciation warnings.

This block of code is being particularly difficult for me. It's returning Depreciations for iOS 11.0 even. I mean to say...

```
1. JPEGPhotoDataRepresentationForJPEGSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use -[AVCapturePhoto fileDataRepresentation] instead.

2. Block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior
Insert 'self->'
3. Incompatible pointer types sending 'CMSampleBufferRef *' (aka 'struct opaqueCMSampleBuffer **') to parameter of type 'CMSampleBufferRef _Nullable' (aka 'struct opaqueCMSampleBuffer *'); dereference with *
Replace '_previewPhotoSampleBuffer' with '*(_previewPhotoSampleBuffer)'




        // Flash set to Auto for Still Capture
    [CameraViewController setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeAuto forDevice:[[self videoDeviceInput] device]];

    // Capture a still image.
    [[self stillImageOutput] captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:[[self stillImageOutput] connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageDataSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

        if (imageDataSampleBuffer)
        {    
            NSData *imageData = [AVCapturePhotoOutput JPEGPhotoDataRepresentationForJPEGSampleBuffer:imageDataSampleBuffer previewPhotoSampleBuffer:_previewPhotoSampleBuffer];

            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            [[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init] writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:nil];
        }
    }];
});
```

Comment: is this possible to attach your sample project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `JPEGPhotoDataRepresentationForJPEGSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:` method was deprecated in iOS 11 due to new support for the HEIC codec for images. As the warning states, you should use `-[AVCapturePhoto fileDataRepresentation]` instead. If you actually need a preview image, use the `AVCapturePhoto.previewPixelBuffer` property.
2. This warning is because the block passed as the completion handler to `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:connectionWithMediaType: completionHandler:` uses `_previewPhotoSampleBuffer` which is (presumably) an instance variable of the class this code is in. When you access an instance variable, what you're actually doing is `self->_previewPhotoSampleBuffer`. Because `self` is needed for that, the block captures it, potentially creating a retain cycle. The compiler warns you because without the explicit use of `self`, you're less likely to notice that yourself. You can silence the warning by doing `self->_previewPhotoSampleBuffer`, but I think the changes to fix warning 1 will remove this code anyway.
3. It appears that `_previewPhotoSampleBuffer` has been declared as a `CMSampleBufferRef *` (in other words, a pointer to a `CMSampleBufferRef`). However, `CMSampleBufferRef` is already a pointer. It's a typedef for `opaqueCMSampleBuffer *`. So you're passing a pointer to a pointer into a method that expects a single pointer, aka a `CMSampleBufferRef`. You'll need to fix this wherever you declare `_previewPhotoSampleBuffer`.